# I continuously receive `Invalid HTTP_HOST header` error email after I upgrade my django site from http to https

Tags: python, django, http, nginx, https

Recently, I upgrade one of my django sites from http to https. However, after that, I continuously receive `Invalid HTTP_HOST header` error email while before I never received such type of emails.

Here are some log messages:

> [Django] ERROR (EXTERNAL IP): Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '123.56.221.107'. You may need to add '123.56.221.107' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
>
> ---
>
> [Django] ERROR (EXTERNAL IP): Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'www.sgsrec.com'. You may need to add 'www.sgsrec.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
>
> ---
>
> [Django] ERROR (EXTERNAL IP): Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'sgsrec.com'. You may need to add 'sgsrec.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
>
> Report at /apple-app-site-association Invalid HTTP_HOST header: ‘sgsrec.com’. You may need to add ‘sgsrec.com’ to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
>
> ---
>
> Invalid HTTP_HOST header: ‘www.pythonzh.cn’. You may need to add ‘www.pythonzh.cn’ to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
>
> Report at / Invalid HTTP_HOST header: ‘www.pythonzh.cn’. You may need to add ‘www.pythonzh.cn’ to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
>
> Request Method: GET Request URL: http://www.pythonzh.cn/ Django Version: 1.10.6
>
> ---
>
> [Django] ERROR (EXTERNAL IP): Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'pythonzh.cn'. You may need to add 'pythonzh.cn' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.

**What the strange thing is that I only change my blog site `www.zmrenwu.com` nginx configuration, but seems all of my sites which hosted on 123.56.221.107 are effected.**

Of cause, I set ALLOWED_HOSTS correctly:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.zmrenwu.com']
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.sgsrec.com']
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.pythonzh.cn']
```

Nginx configuration of my blog site `www.zmrenwu.com`:

```
server {
    charset utf-8;
    server_name zmrenwu.com www.zmrenwu.com;
    listen 80;
    return 301 https://www.zmrenwu.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    charset utf-8;
    server_name zmrenwu.com;
    listen 443;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/1_www.zmrenwu.com_bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/2_www.zmrenwu.com.key;

    return 301 https://www.zmrenwu.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    charset utf-8;
    listen 443;
    server_name www.zmrenwu.com;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/1_www.zmrenwu.com_bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/2_www.zmrenwu.com.key;

    location /static  {
        alias /home/yangxg/sites/zmrenwu.com/blogproject/static;
    }

    location /media {
        alias /home/yangxg/sites/zmrenwu.com/blogproject/media;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/tmp/zmrenwu.com.socket;
```

Why that happened? And How could I solve this issue?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to add in a block

```
   location / {

   }
```

this condition (for not-yourdomain request):

```
if ( $host !~* ^(yourdomain.com|www.yourdomain.com)$ ) {
   return 444;
}
```

and

```
sudo service nginx reload
```

Comment: @solarissmoke The only 100% safe things which may be done inside if in a location context are: `return ...;` `rewrite ... last`

Comment: In your answer is block 2 supposed to be inside block 1? Or are both blocks needed separately? I have block 2 alone but it doesn't seem to work by itself. Please clarify.

Comment: I already have a location block with proxy_pass directive. I also have multiple location blocks (static, media etc.) Currently my block2 is outside the location blocks and it does not seem to work.

Answer (score 26):

Disabling `DisallowedHost` host warnings as suggested in the other answer is not the correct solution in my opinion. There is a reason why Django gives you those warnings - and it is better for you to block those requests before they reach Django.

You created a new server block in your nginx configuration. Because it is the only HTTPS server you have defined, it becomes the default server for that port. From the [documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html#how_to_prevent_undefined_server_names):

> The `default_server` parameter, if present, will cause the server to become the default server for the specified `address:port` pair. If none of the directives have the `default_server` parameter then the first server with the `address:port` pair will be the default server for this pair.

This explains why you are suddenly seeing all these invalid host errors. Any bot that now tries to connect to your server over HTTPS will end up using this default server. Because many bots will be using fake host names or just your server IP (neither of which are in `ALLOWED_HOSTS`) this causes the warnings in Django.

So what is the solution? You can create a separate server block that handles all such invalid requests:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 444;
}
```

`444` is a special response status used by nginx to [disconnect invalid requests](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html#how_to_prevent_undefined_server_names).

Once you add this block, it will be used for all requests that don't match the host headers that you want to respond to, and anything trying to connect with an invalid host will not be able to connect.

Django meanwhile will stop seeing requests for invalid hosts.

Comment: What does the `_` for `server_name` do?

Comment: _ is just an invalid value which will never trigger on a real hostname.

Comment: be aware that if nginx is behind an ALB, then you might also also drop health check requests which may affect uptime

Comment: This solution was not immediately compatible with my certbot ssl settings.

Answer (score -1):

This is probably because there may be bot scripts running which are targeting your server with different HTTP_HOST headers (this is common). and in django you have Allowed Hosts set to a particular host. So if a Host Header different from one specified in Allowed Hosts come then django would give 400 error.
By default django loggers are configured to send mail on each error. To stop getting the mails you need to configure loggers in django and add the 
following logger
`'django.security.DisallowedHost': {
        'handlers': ['null'],
        'propagate': False,
},`

Refer https://www.calazan.com/how-to-disable-the-invalid-http_host-header-emails-in-django/

Comment: Thanks! But why before upgrading to https, I hadn't reveived any such error email? It that just a coincidence?

Comment: This will just  disable notifications, but will not eliminate the cause. You will still get those errors but will not be reported. Solution should restrit such request to reach django application.