# Invalid HTTP_HOST header - Django

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I started receiving a lot of invalid HTTP_HOST on my django server, out of nowhere....

The allowed_hosts are correct, I think someone is trying to break in... here are the fails:

> Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'www.google.com'. You may need to add 'www.google.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
>
> Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '127.0.0.1:30303'. You may need to add '127.0.0.1' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.
>
> Invalid HTTP_HOST header: '/home/site/myapp.sock:'. The domain name provided is not valid according to RFC 1034/1035.
>
> Invalid HTTP_HOST header: 'xxxx.members.linode.com'. You may need to add 'xxxx.members.linode.com' to ALLOWED_HOSTS.

Any idea why this starts happening?

**EDIT**
nginx conf:

```
 server {
    listen 8000;
    server_name www.myserverdomain.com;

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/site/bla/;
    }
    location /media/ {
        root /home/site/bla/;
    }

location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/site/app.sock;
    }

}
```

Comment: Can we see how nginx config looks like?

Comment: @Alex just added it

Comment: what is your DEBUG and ALLOWED_HOSTS settings in django on that server? is this an api with a SPA frontend?

Comment: @Walucas have you tried listening on 80 rather than 8000?

Comment: debug false, ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['domain.com','www.mydomain.com']

Comment: I have apache running on 80

Comment: reading online, this port 30303 is a Ethereum mining port, maybe someone hacked in....

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47846521/i-continuously-receive-invalid-http-host-header-error-email-after-i-upgrade-my