# Kubernetes nginx ingress - block requests with bad host headers

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

I've a Django application running behind Nginx ingress on Kubernetes. I wish to block requests that are sent with bad host headers (that are looking to do a host header exploit/cache poisoning).

To block these requests at the Nginx layer, I know I can add a server block with the `default_server` parameter as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47851675/131050).

However, I am not sure how to do that in Kubernetes via the externalingress yaml. I came across this [PR](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/85) which seemed relevant, but could not figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that in two ways: via `server-snippet` [annotation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#server-snippet) or by overriding existing Nginx Ingress Controller's [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/configmap/#configmaps).

Example from documentation, how to update server configuration block in related `nginx.conf` file for underlying `nginx-ingress-controller` Pod via `server-snippet` annotation:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/server-snippet: |
        set $agentflag 0;

        if ($http_user_agent ~* "(Mobile)" ){
          set $agentflag 1;
        }

        if ( $agentflag = 1 ) {
          return 301 https://m.example.com;
        }
```

ConfigMap requires also `server-snippet` parameter in order to propagate configuration to `nginx-ingress-controller` Pod:

```
kind: ConfigMap
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: ingress-nginx-ingress-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
data:
  server-snippet: |
    set $agentflag 0;

        if ($http_user_agent ~* "(Mobile)" ){
          set $agentflag 1;
        }

        if ( $agentflag = 1 ) {
          return 301 https://m.example.com;
        }
```