# How to block bots in Nginx by stopping Invalid Host Headers

Tags: nginx

I have tried a ton of different things to stop bots from hitting my backend but cannot seem to block invalid host headers without blocking all traffic. My current configuration looks as such:

```
# trying to stop invalid host headers which doesn't work
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    return 444;
}

upstream backend_server {
    server backend:8000;
}

server {
    listen 80;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    location ~* ^/(api|admin|static|v2) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    location / {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    server_name example.com *.example.com;
    deny 143.198.76.27; # trying to stop certain IPs here which doesn't work

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location ~ ^/v2(?:/(.*))?$ {
        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /v2/index.html =404;
    }

    location /backend_static/ {      
        alias /backend/assets/;
    }

    location /media/ {      
        alias /backend/media/;
    }

    location ~* ^/(api|admin) {
        proxy_pass http://backend_server$request_uri;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $https;
        proxy_connect_timeout 360s;
        proxy_read_timeout 360s;
    }

    location ~* ^/(videos|notes|memos|images|policies|documents|files|uploads|static) {
        proxy_pass http://backend_server$request_uri;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $https;
        proxy_connect_timeout 360s;
        proxy_read_timeout 360s;
        # Set upload size for videos to be 500MB
        client_max_body_size 500M;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://backend_server$request_uri;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $https;
        proxy_connect_timeout 360s;
        proxy_read_timeout 360s;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically to block bots who sends invalid `Host` header you need something like this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name mydomain.com;
    
    if ( $host !~* ^(mydomain.com|www.mydomain.com)$ ) {
        return 444;
    }

    if ( $http_host !~* ^(mydomain.com|www.mydomain.com)$ ) {
        return 444;
    }

}
```

But there are plenty of other options (because almost all bots have tendency to adapt), like cookie tests, javascript or even CAPTCHa.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried handling it this way but it was blocking all requests. I am not sure if it has to do with the wildcard or not. The reason I am trying to block it is I get Django log emails which tell me invalid host headers constantly and I only want the emails which are real issues. Therefore trying to stop the bots at the server level.

Comment: @DavidAlford If you are dealing with email problem (SPAM, etc.) you should use proper instruments, not web-server. If I understood you correctly.

Comment: They are Django admin log emails - anytime there is a site error. e.g. Invalid Host Headers causes the site error. It isn't SPAM, it is malicious bots trying to collect info from the site using Invalid Host Headers (I assume to show stack trace if someone left DEBUG on in production).

Comment: @DavidAlford ok then, you can do it other way - just create `server {}` configuration with `default_server` block which will handle all requests with `Host: ` header you doesn't want to handle or by legitimate `server {}` blocks:  http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html

Comment: @DavidAlford, they are malicious/buggy bots, but they don't target Django installs. I also have those logs/mails, and they request Wordpress php and similar endpoints. You can disable mail report for these errors as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47847614/1688590

Comment: I stopped the email reports but that doesn't solve the issue, it just hides it. The issue is that the bots are getting passed Nginx. I would rather they be stopped at Nginx.